# Export database structure as "alter table" so that structure will get updated

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, synchronization

I need to use PHPMyAdmin to export my database structure so that the output file, when executed, will update structure of all tables. I did many minor changes and I need to apply them on the online website version.
I can't see any setting that would make PHPMyAdmin do that. Could I eventually edit the output myself easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature at the export level. However, if you had activated the phpMyAdmin configuration storage, you could have enabled tracking on your tables, and in the tracking report, you would have seen all the ALTER TABLE statements generated between, say, version 1 and version 2 of your structure.

Answer (score 2):

[Schema Sync](http://schemasync.org/) is quite good lightweight command line tool for this.